# print by username in rdlc report

Tags: c#

can someone help me im creating a rdlc report of online overtime thru c# my objective is when u click the report it will print in different paper sort by username for example, username:dennis , joana ,hanna. when i print it will print in 3 paper paper1=dennis,paper2=joana,paper3=hanna here are the pictures in picture 1 its the page 1 see the name that been encircle and in picture 2 the encircle name must be like in notedby name.

http://postimg.org/image/vr25f3txb/ -- picture1

http://postimg.org/image/dsy6ixmqb/ -- picture 2

Comment: This seems to be an errror in your query, rather then a problem for the report. Just make sure that 'Noted by' is correctly filled in...

Comment: this is not  an error  thats why it got a result see the noted by in table they are correct when i put it in the footer of the report only the 1st name are printed in all page

Comment: Maybe return a extra column created in the query that contains one string with all the approvers in that string for every row you return and assign that string to the footer...